# PHP returning references

Tags: php, reference

I have read the section of returning references in PHP by putting the ampersand in both the function definition and variable assignment. But, I have yet to find examples of "returning references" in php code that does not relate to Object Oriented Programming. Can anyone provide a use for this and an example?

Comment: You want a real life example or just a technical example? By the way, please go back and accept answers to your old questions... 25% is a pretty low rate.

Comment: passing objects by reference is deprecated in php these days.  You can just pass the whole object.

Comment: Returning references to non-objects is also possible. Imagine a nested array storing a menu tree with nodes and child nodes, a function that finds a specific menu item and returns a reference to it (so you can modify its content and childd nodes) would be a good use case. (For example, Drupal uses arrays like that everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks @DCoder I think that array example did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start, from a very simplified example,

```
class Test {

    //Public intentionally
    //Because we are going to access it directly later
    //in order to see if it's changed
    public $property = 'test';

    /**
     * Look carefully at getPropReference() title
     * we have an ampersand there, that is we're indicating
     * that we're returning a reference to the class property
     * 
     * @return string A reference to $property
     */
    public function &getPropReference()
    {
         return $this->property;
    }
}


$test = new Test();

//IMPORTANT!! Assign to $_foo a reference, not a copy!
//Otherwise, it does not make sense at all
$_foo =& $test->getPropReference();

//Now when you change a $_foo the property of an $test object would be changed as well
$_foo = "another string";

// As you can see the public property of the class
// has been changed as well
var_dump($test->property); // Outputs: string(14) "another string" 

$_foo = "yet another string";
var_dump($test->property);   //Outputs "yet another string"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update: This answer relates to passing by reference, not returning by reference.  Retained for it's information value.**

Read this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Then take a look at this example:

```
<?php
function AddTimestamp(&$mytimes)
{
    $mytimes[] = time();
}


$times = array();
AddTimestamp($times);
AddTimestamp($times);
AddTimestamp($times);

// Result is an array with 3 timestamps.
```

Can this be better implemented using object oriented techniques?  Perhaps, but from time to time there is a need/reason to modify an existing value-based data structure or variable.

Consider this:

```
function ValidateString(&$input, &$ErrorList)
{
   $input = trim($input);
   if(strlen($input) < 1 || strlen($input) > 10) 
   {
      $ErrorList[] = 'Input must be between 1 and 10 characters.';
      return False;
   }
} 

$Err = array();
$Name = '  Jason    ';

ValidateString($Name, $Err);

// At this point, $Name is trimmed. If there was an error, $Err has the message.
```

So, depending on your needs, there are still times to pass by reference in PHP.  Objects are always passed by reference, so anytime you encapsulate your data in an object, it automatically becomes a reference.

Comment: It's passing reference, not returning them

Comment: I appreciate your input but my question is with regards to returning references not passing by reference.